# Powershell - No value on AD Description fields

Tags: powershell

I had run the ps command under PowerShell ISE to query the users with fields as below, but it seems have no value output on some fields (such as Description). I checked the Description field under "Active Directory Users and Computers" tools and it have text in it, but when running the ps command, it's blank.

Here is the ps command of mine:

```
Get-ADUser -Filter "(Company -like '*United Kingdom*') -And (Enabled -eq 'True')" | 
Format-Table GivenName, Surname,Description,SamAccountName
```

How can I get powershell to display the string value in "Description" field?

Thanks with Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note: this question has already been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44710480/4749264). I wasn't cognizant of that when I posted the original answer.  However, I'll try to enhance below to add more information.

For performance and query efficiency reasons `Get-ADUser` doesn't return all the available attributes by default.  You can use the `-Properties` parameter with either a scalar or array argument to instruct `Get-ADUser` to retrieve additional properties.

In your case an example like below would work:

```
Get-ADUser -Filter "(Company -like '*United Kingdom*') -And (Enabled -eq 'True')" -Properties 'Description'| 
Format-Table GivenName, Surname,Description,SamAccountName
```

However, when retrieving multiple additional properties I've found this quickly becomes unwieldy. So, an alternate approach is to define an array variable for reference in the command:

```
$ADProps =
@(
    'Description'
    'lastLogon'
    'company'
)

Get-ADUser -Filter "(Company -like '*United Kingdom*') -And (Enabled -eq 'True')" -Properties $ADProps
```

During development, or maintenance this allows easy modification without necessarily having to modify the `Get-ADUser` command.